# Load multiple csv files and do iterative calculation for each file

Tags: procedural-programming, automation

I am trying to read multiple csv files and want to plot them all together, 
Lets say I have 3 files, file1 , file2 and file3
I want to average 3 files, and plot them all together, 
So far I have set up like this:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

and I load files like this:

```
files = FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "*.csv"];
Do[Print["Processing file ", files[[n]]];
 processFile[files[[n]]], {n, 1, Length[files]}]
```

```
processFile[fileName_]:=
 Module[{data2},
  data2 = Import[fileName, "Data"];
  tables = Table[data2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data2]}]]
```

now, here is where I have problem:
I am giving a name for each `processFile` and do other calculations:

```
d1 = processFile["file1.csv"];
d2 = processFile["file2.csv"];
d3 = processFile["file3.csv"];
avg = (d1 + d2 + d3)/3;
avgplot = ListPlot[avg, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 1}}];
```

I am having trouble automating d1,d2,d3 (I want this automated to no matter how many files I have and so I don't have to manually insert their names and define multiple times)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe `files // Map[processFile[#]&] // Mean`?

Answer (score 1):

What do your CSV files contain?  Single columns? Multiple columns?

In any case ...

Generate some data, then export it:

```
test = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 1024}];
test = Transpose[{Range[1024], #}] & /@ test;
Export["file_" <> IntegerString[#, 10, 2] <> ".csv", test[[#]]] & /@ 
  Range[Length@test];
```

Using your function with a small correction to restrict the scope of `tables`:

```
processFile[fileName_] := Module[
  {data2, tables},
  data2 = Import[fileName, "Data"];
  tables = Table[data2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[data2]}]
  ]
```

We can import the data & plot it:

```
ifile = FileNames["*.csv"];
proc = processFile[#] & /@ ifile;
ListPlot[proc, PlotStyle -> {Black, Gray, Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

But you want to take the average. Lets do that for the first three files & plot the result:

```
avg = proc[[1, All, 2]] + proc[[2, All, 2]] + proc[[3, All, 2]];
avg = Transpose[{proc[[1, All, 1]], avg/3.}];
ListPlot[tavg]
```

[image]

We can also average all the imported data:

```
tavg = Mean@proc[[All, All, 2]];
tavg = Transpose[{proc[[1, All, 1]], tavg}];
```

But perhaps a more elegant way is:

```
idat = Import[#] & /@ ifile;
iavg = Mean[idat];
```

which imports the data into a single 4 x 1024 x 2 array (`idat`), then averages those data.

Comment: what is &/@ ifile in your code? Mathematica 9 , the one i use doesn't recognize ifile

Comment: ifile = FileNames["*.csv"];

Comment: dwa, can you please edit this clarifying comment content into your answer?